# What do you use for search form? get queries or route params?

Tags: zend-framework, search, seo, routes, zend-framework2

I'm building up a search form, but i don't know if it's better to use the classical get queries or to create a custom url that can match with my router.

GET

- Url: http://mysite.com/search/?q=query+param&p=2
- Advantage: No js required, analytics search tool friendly
- Disadvantage: Not seo friendly

ROUTE

- Url: http://mysite.com/search/query+param/2
- Advantage: Seo friendly
- Disadvantage: js required, need to urlencode, must implement extra analytics code

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a definitive answer yet on which is best, but most people have been using /term/definition/term/definition in the URLs for a while because that USED to be the best for SEO.  However, Google (and the other guys) have made some progress.  Check out this  [Google Webmaster Blog entry](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/07/improved-handling-of-urls-with.html) - it seems that they have a bit more intelligence when doing search items.

My general rule is I use get parameters for actual searching, and URLs for categories (or browsing) - I believe this is the most intuitive.  And, like it looks now... the search engines are being better equiped to index and search URL parameters anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom route definition in your module config:

```
'search' => array(
  'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
  'options' => array(
    'route' => 'search[/:query][/:page]'
```

You can then parse the query parameters using the `params()` action helper in your controller:

```
$query = $this->params()->fromRoute('query');
$page = $this->params()->fromRoute('page');
```

In your views you can use the `url()` view helper to build urls with the same route definition:

```
$this->url('search', array('query' => 'test', 'page' => '1'));
```

Just use a GET request. There is no need for a POST request here.

Hope that helps!

Best regards,
Jurgen

Comment: pardon, i know how to accomplish that, but i want to know what is the best solution. if to use the first (http://mysite.com/search/?q=query+param&p=2) or the second kind of url (http://mysite.com/search/query+param/2)

Comment: Although both options are fine, the second approach is better: it looks "cleaner", keeps url's shorter, allows for conditions in your routing config in ZF2 and is great for sending url's in emails.